# SSRS Data Driven Subscriptions Link Not Correct

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have some SSRS data driven subscriptions that have both a link getting sent and links within the report. Neither are coming over correctly.

For example, the links are all coming over as http://ServerName:ServerPort/RestOfLink

I have my URL Root set, and the logs show that:

Using url root http://DOMAIN.net/Reports.

SSRS is in SharePoint Integrated mode

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was the order in which the alternate active mappings were set up. The URL embedded was the one for the default zone. Switched the domain URL to the default zone and we're rolling now.